# IE8 doesn't import pac script post installation

Tags: internet-explorer-8

IE8 doesn't import pac script post installation. Doesn anyone know what could be the reason ?

Comment: Well it works just fine for me, so IE is perfectly capable of doing it. You might try sharing a few more details of what you're doing, what you've tried already and what the relevant parts of your network (e.g. where are you attempting to import the PAC file *from*) look like if you want help troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 0):

IE 8 doesn't support IsinNet function in the same way as previous versions of IE. Check out this article:

http://www.thewaystation.com/techref/proxy/pac/pacfileie8issue.shtml

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, issue we are still facing is GPO is not getting applied even after successful IE8 installation. Tried reboot / logging off twice but still not working. And as GPO is not applied, automatic configuration script is not detected and hence Internet does not work. Internet works properly with FF, but IE8 it doesn't!